# ContentEditable in Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to create a Polymer element for contenteditable.

I create a `contenteditable` div, place `this.innerHTML` there, and it becomes editable. All good with polyfills, e.g. in Firefox. But it doesn't work in Chrome 35 with native Shadow DOM.

Well, it is still editable, but neither `document.execCommand` nor `window.getSelection` is working.

- `document.execCommand` does nothing.
- `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString()` is defined but empty.
- No error is shown.

So I cannot style the selection.

Does anybody know whether it's possible to make a custom editable element or not? What am I doing wrong? Maybe there's another way to work with contenteditable in modern/future web?

Comment: This looks interesting, post a link to your code if you release it.

Comment: @PeterBurns I got another problem working with Chrome 35 -- Range object is incorrect, so I cannot say what styles are applied for selected range, or position a toolbar near selection boundaries. It looks like a Chrome bug, maybe nobody have tried to do what I am doing. If you want to take a look on WIP code, I can release it for you. Otherwise I better wait a bit for better Shadow DOM stability. (yep everything works great with polyfills, but it isn't of any value.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the spec [1](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#ranges-and-selections) selection is somewhat open ended for implementors. It does mention:

> Accordingly, selections may only exist within one node tree, because they are defined by a single range. The selection, returned by the `window.getSelection()` method never returns a selection within a shadow tree.
>
> The `getSelection()` method of the shadow root object returns the current selection in this shadow tree.

Have you tried the shadow root's `getSelection()`?

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying now. Searching for a way also to style the selection :) something like execCommand -- to wrap/unwrap selection with a tag or anchor.

Comment: getSelection() works on shadowRoot, but getRangeAt(0) is an empty range, `.surroundContents(document.createElement("strong"));` does nothing, document.execCommand doesn't work :( so Selection is just useless

Comment: it looks like it could be hacked around. Thanks again!

Comment: @DmitryKurinskiy: How did you hack it around?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, I have stopped these experiments about a year ago :(

Comment: @RobertKoritnik don't know if you'd find it useful, but there's a large thread on this here: https://github.com/guardian/scribe/issues/329

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
const selection = shadowRoot.getSelection();
const range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
console.log(range.toString())
```