# ShadowRoot's getSelection().getRangeAt(0) returns incorrect Range object in Google Chrome 35

Tags: javascript, html, dart, polymer, shadow-dom

We're working on an application for our customer that uses dart lang with polymer components. One of our custom components namely datagrid uses `<div contenteditable></div>` for entering values to the datagrid cells. I also want to provide custom formatting capabilities so I had to override keypress event. The problem araises when I want to create new HTML nodes at the caret position within the content-editable *div* element in Chrome 35 (possibly all webkit browsers that support Shadow DOM natively, not through polyfills).

When I use `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)` to get current caret position, new nodes are being added to the beginning of the *body* element instead of the *div*. In Firefox and IE 11 it works great though (using polyfill).

When I tried `this.shadowRoot.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882272/contenteditable-in-shadow-dom/23882566#23882566) it didn't work as well because it returns incorrect Range object (a bug or a feature?). However when I logged the Selection object, it seems like all offsets are correct so it means that it can be worked around somehow but the guy that asked similar question on SO hasn't posted how he did it.

So I don't know, how to create a Range object from given offset when content-editable *div* contains multiple HTML nodes as browsers like to create multiple nodes when you put a line break into the middle of the word and delete it immediately (as a side question, is it normal anyways? doesn't it cause memory leaks?). It then looks like this in a Chrome console (#cell-input here has 4 nodes although it just contains continuous string "Marek"):

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="cell-input">
    "M"
    "ar"
    "ek"
    <br>
</div>
```

I tried to use something like (it's just a pseudocode):

```
offset = shadowRoot.getSelection().extentOffset;
element = document.querySelector('cell-input');

range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(element.children.first, offset );
range.setEnd(element.children.first, offset);
range.collapse(false);
```

... but it didn't work properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it is a bug reported by me [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=380690) and confirmed by the chromium team at the end of the issue thread.

Comment: This is now resolved in Chrome 42 I believe so we are only waiting for the fix to get to stable version sooner or later. Please read the issue thread where also a temporary solution has been published by me. Although not 100% but still.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a plunk which shows how we can save shadowRoot selection range and use it when needed.
Problem is this.shadowRoot.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) returns incorrect range, you've to create range from this.shadowRoot.getSelection() by getSelection().setStart, getSelection().setEnd. For more understanding see the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/B8TpQJ?p=preview)

```
shadowRoot.getSelection.getRangeAt(0) instead use  
var selRange=document.createRange();
var shadowRootSelection = this.shadowRoot.getSelection();
selRange.setStart(shadowRootSelection.anchorNode, shadowRootSelection.anchorOffset);
        selRange.setEnd(shadowRootSelection.focusNode, shadowRootSelection.focusOffset);
```

Comment: Yea that's basically what we found out during the investigation and what I have implemented a while ago, the link can be found in the Dart bug tracker issue but here's it: http://jsfiddle.net/mareksuscak/kd96T/6/

But please note that it's not 100% solution because the direction is not exposed so you don't know which node comes first (anchorNode or focusNode). For more information read the last comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=380690#c21